# Tengo un problema al intentar validar un formulario usando jQuery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

estoy realizando un login para un trabajo, pero al momento de intentar realizar una validacion con jQuery validator simplemente no funciona, no se si se trate de un error al vincularlo mediante los scripts pero cualquier ayuda es mas que bienvenida. En seguida les adjunto mi codigo. Cabe resaltar que estoy usando HTML5.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/adminlte.css">
</head>
<body class="login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="login-logo">
            <a href="#"><strong>Institucion </strong></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body login-card-body">
                <p class="login-box-msg">Inicia sesión</p>
                <form action="#" method="post" id="login">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="" id="correo" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="" id="contra" placeholder="Contraseña">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="" id="confirmContra" placeholder="Confirmar Contraseña">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Cancelar &#10008</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="registro">Registrate &#10003</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
aqui termina el apartado de el formulario, a continuacion pondre los scripts y mi intento fallido de validar el campo de "nombre"

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/adminlte.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/additional-methods.js"></script>

    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $.validator.setDefaults({
                submitHandler: function(){
                    alert("Enviado");
                }
            });
          $("#login").submit(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
          }).validate({
              rules:{
                  "nombre":{
                      required: true
                    },
                },
                messages:{
                    "nombre":{
                        required:"Ingresa tu nombre"
                    },
                },

                errorElement: "em",
                errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                    error.addClass("help-block");
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Se que es mucho codigo para revisar pero en serio necesito ayuda, no se si se trate de mis vinculaciones, en todo caso estaria feliz de enviar mas informacion respecto al contenido de mis carpetas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo te faltaría agregar a todos los `name=""` su identificador, además de cambiar el `type="submit"` por `type="button"` al botón Cancelar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
      alert("Enviado");
    }
  });
  $("#login").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }).validate({
    rules: {
      "nombre": {
        required: true
      },
      "apellidos": {
        required: true
      },
      "correo": {
        required: true
      },
      "telefono": {
        required: true
      },
      "contra": {
        required: true
      },
      "confirmContra": {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      "nombre": {
        required: "Ingresa tu nombre"
      },
      "apellidos": {
        required: "Ingresa tus apellidos"
      },
      "correo": {
        required: "Ingresa tu correo"
      },
      "telefono": {
        required: "Ingresa tu teléfono"
      },
      "contra": {
        required: "Ingresa tu contraseña"
      },
      "confirmContra": {
        required: "Ingresa tu contraseña"
      }
    },

    errorElement: "em",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.attr('type') == "text") {
        error.addClass("help-block");
        error.insertAfter(element.parent('div'));
      } else {
        error.addClass("help-block");
        error.insertAfter(element.parent('div'));
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form method="post" id="login">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="contra" id="contra" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmContra" id="confirmContra" placeholder="Confirmar Contraseña">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Cancelar &#10008</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="registro">Registrate &#10003</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias eso soluciono mi problema, solo tengo uno nuevo donde el mensaje de error se muestra dentro de la caja de texto, en vez de fuera de la misma

Comment: Para eso podrías usar una condición dentro de tu función `errorPlacement` haciendo un `insertAfter(element.parent('div'));` puedes usar otros padres del elemento o usar otras condiciones para que vayas probando y ver como te quedan. Te edito la respuesta para que tú mismo lo veas.

Comment: Muchas gracias en verdad me salvaste la vida

Answer (score 0):

Ok trata segun el ejemplo de la libreria:

```
<script>
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function(){
            alert("Enviado");
        }
    });

     $().ready(function(){
        $("#login").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        }).validate({
            rules:{
                "nombre":{
                    required: true
                },
            },
            messages:{
                "nombre":{
                    required:"Ingresa tu nombre"
                },
            },

            errorElement: "em",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                error.addClass("help-block");
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Entonces lo cambiado a submit?, muchas gracias por responer.

Comment: ¿No es un tanto redundante decir que una etiqueta button sea de tipo button?

Comment: no cambia a type="button"  y dime que pasa. no se puede recrear tu escript porque no se sabe como tus libraries corren.

Comment: no. porque button adentro de un formulario hace submit imediatamente. Si el formulario es Method=POST entonces manda $_POST al target.

Comment: Si pero como el ya maneja JS entonces lo puede dejar solo como button y capturar su evento submit para prevenirlo

Comment: Ya cambie el tipo a button y simplemente cuando doy click no hace nada, creo que el tipo si tiene que ser submit, de otro modo el formulario no se envia

Comment: pero quien hace validate? validate es un libreria de js.  No veo que le hagas echo bind a ningun objeto. Como es que validata va a correr?

Comment: No es necesario cambiar el `type=submit` del  boton Registrate, sino solo el de cancelar sacarle el `type`

Comment: Validate es de jquery validate para validar valga la redundancia, o al menos es la manera en la que me enseño mi profesor, ahora intentare sacarle el type a el boton cancelar

Comment: La cuestion es que al momento de enviar el formulario me sale la alerta de enviado, pero no se realizan ninguna de las validaciones

Comment: @JonathanSerafnContrerasMalf  trata cambia tu escript segun la libreria. deja tus button type="submit"   ( compea la nueva respuesta. )

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, intentare ver que mis scripts esten bien vinculados, gracias.